# Submit U-SQL Script locally using Powershell

Tags: powershell, azure-data-lake, u-sql

If I want to submit a `U-SQL` Script to ADLA account, I can do so, using the below `powershell` cmdlet.

```
`
Submit-AzureRmDataLakeAnalyticsJob -Account $adlaAccountName -ScriptPath $USQLFile -Name $folder -DegreeOfParallelism $degreeOfParallelism -Verbose`
```

But, I am not able to submit the script against local ADLA account. I am getting error:

`Submit-AzureRmDataLakeAnalyticsJob : Run Login-AzureRmAccount to login.
At line:1 char:1
+ Submit-AzureRmDataLakeAnalyticsJob -Account "local" -ScriptPath GetIn ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Submit-AzureRmDataLakeAnalyticsJob], PSInvalidOperationExceptio 
   n
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidOperation,Microsoft.Azure.Commands.DataLakeAnalytics.SubmitAzureDataLakeAnalyti 
   csJob`

How to submit U-SQL script against local ADLA account ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to ADL Tools,  we have released standalone SDK as well.

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.DataLake.USQL.SDK

And document here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-lake-analytics/data-lake-analytics-data-lake-tools-local-run

Thanks a lot,
Yu Dong